# Are compact complete geodesics closed?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. 
Is there an example of a geodesic $c:\mathbb{R}\to M$ s.t. $c(\mathbb{R})$ is compact, $c$ is NOT periodic (i.e. be NOT a closed geodesic) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm assuming you mean a smooth Riemannian manifold.)  I really struggled with this problem.  Here is my outline of an attempt.

First consider this as a special case of the following:

**Theorem.** If $X$ is a smooth vector field on a manifold $N$, and $f:\mathbb R \to N$ is a solution to the differential equation $\dot f(t) = Xf(t)$, then either $f(t_1) = f(t_2)$ for some $t_1 \ne t_2$ (and hence $f$ is periodic or constant), or the image $f(\mathbb R)$ is not compact.

How to prove the theorem?  $X$ defines a group action $T$ by $\mathbb R$ onto $N$ where $T(t)(p) = f(t)$, with $f$ solving the ODE $\dot f(t) = Xf(t)$, $f(0) = p$.  Now if $f(\mathbb R)$ is compact but not periodic or constant, then there must be one point on $f(\mathbb R)$ that is a limit point.  But since the action $T$ is continuous, and transitive on $f(\mathbb R)$, it follows that $f(\mathbb R)$ is a perfect subset of $N$.

Find a codimension $1$ submanifold $B$ (not compact, eg like a small open subset of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$) in a neighborhood of $f(0)$ that is transversal to the flow $X$, that is, $X$ is never parallel to $TB$.  Persuade yourself that the closure of $B$ intersect $f(\mathbb R)$ must be a perfect set.  But $f(\mathbb R)$ can only hit $B$ countably many times.  And a perfect set must be uncountable.

Now to answer your question: apply the above to the vector field $X$ on $N = TM$ that on any chart takes $(p,v)$ to $(v,\phi(p,v))$, where $\ddot p = \phi(p,\dot p)$ is the usual Euler-Lagrange equation that defines a geodesic.  So the image $f(\mathbb R) \subset TM$ is not compact.  Suppose for a contradiction that $\pi(f(\mathbb R))$ is compact where $\pi:TM \to M$ is the canonical projection.

Here I am stuck!

Comment: Can you further explain your action $T$? Is that $f$ defined by $T$ a geodesic on $M$? (Is it an action on $TM$?)

Comment: @John The theorem doesn't mention geodesics.  So the action $T$ has nothing to do with geodesics.  $T(t)$ simply means "follow the flow $X$ for time $t$."

Comment: But isn't that $X$ is a vector field on $TM$? So $T$ should be the action on $TM$? (I am talking about second last paragraph)

Comment: No.  In the third to last paragraph I apply the theorem to $TM$.  The notation is confusing, because the theorem is about $M$, and then I apply the theorem to $M = TM$.  Maybe I should have use different letters.

Comment: @John I changed $M$ to $N$ to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @John and now the action of $T$ on $TM$ simply means "follow a geodesic for time $t$ starting at the point and direction $(p,v) \in TM$."

Comment: I don't think this completely addresses the original question. You are proving that an orbit of the geodesic flow on $TM$ is either periodic or noncompact, whereas the question asks whether a geodesic on $M$ is either periodic or noncompact. So your answer is incomplete unless you can prove that if you have a noncompact orbit of the geodesic flow in $TM$ then its image under the canonical projection $TM \to M$ is noncompact in $M$.

Comment: @LeeMosher You make a good point.  I don't see how to fix it.

Comment: Actually, you proved it. First, look at the geodesic flow on the unit tangent bundle. There each flow line (which you called $f(\mathbb R)$ is either periodic or compact. But you have $f(t) = (\pi\circ f)'(t)$ since $f(t)$ projects to a unit speed geodesic. So if $(\pi\circ f)(t)$ is not periodic or non-compact, the same would be true for $f(t)$.

Comment: There's a simpler proof of the theorem.  If the geodesic is compact, a little playing around with limits will tell you it has a well-defined endpoint, i.e. the limit as $t \to \infty$ exists.  Check to see if the vector field is non-zero at this "end point" and apply the existence and uniqueness theorem to complete the proof.

Comment: @PeterMichor Brilliant!  I think you are correct.

Comment: @RyanBudney Can you outline how you show the endpoints are well defined?

Comment: @PeterMichor OK, I'm missing this part.  If $\pi\circ f$ is non-compact, how do you conclude that $f$ is non-compact?

Comment: If $\vec v(t)$ is a solution, $\vec v(n)$ for $n$ a natural number is a sequence.  So it has a convergent subsequence, being in a compact space. I call this the "endpoint" of the curve.  Now apply the existence and uniqueness theorem to that endpoint.

Comment: @RyanBudney How do you show that $v(t)$ converges to this endpoint as $t \to \infty$?  All you know is that a subsequence converges to this endpoint.

Comment: Technically we don't need to know that, as we've already cornered ourselves into a contradiction using the E&U theorem.

Comment: @RyanBudney How do you use the E&U theorem to finish the proof?

Comment: I believe @RyanBudney 's proof cannot be correct, one can imagine a curve which, roughly, does one revolution which 'looks like' a unit circle, then spirals in, then spirals back out while converges to the original revolution. Such behavior would not be in contradiction to the existence and uniqueness theorem

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, as expected no. What follows is more of a proof sketch than a complete proof. Contradiction is attained in the same fashion as in Stephen M.S.'s answer. We make the obvious assumption $\dim M\geq 2$.

Consider some sequence of real numbers $r_n$ that tends to infinity. By compactness of $c(\Bbb R)$, there is some subsequence, say $s_n$, and some real number $t_0$, such that $c(s_n)\to c(t_0)$. Actually, by compactness of the unit sphere, we may arrange $\dot c(s_n)\to\dot c(t_0)$.

We need to weed out a little annoyance: the point $c(t_0)$ may be reached infinitely often. We can safely assume this is not the case. To convince ourselves, let us consider the map
$$c\times c:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\setminus\Delta\to M\times M,\quad(s,t)\mapsto(c(s),c(t))$$
it has constant rank ($2$, since $\dim M\geq 2$), and is easily seen to be transveral to the diagonal $\Delta_M\subset M\times M$ (otherwise the geodesic would be periodic). Hence the times $t\neq t'$ such that $c(t)=c(t')$ are isolated in $\Bbb R^2$, in the sense that $(c\times c)^{-1}(\Delta_M)$ is a discrete, hence countable, subset of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\setminus\Delta$
.

Thus, for some small $\epsilon>0$, the point $c(t_0+\epsilon)$ is only ever attained once by the curve $c$. Also, the fact that the derivatives $\dot c(s_n)$ converge to $\dot c(t_0)$ readily imply that the derivatives $\dot c(s_n+\epsilon)$ converge to $\dot c(t_0+\epsilon)$. Finally, modulo an affine change of parameter $t\mapsto t+a$ we may assume

> For all $t\neq 0$, $c(t)\neq c(0)$, and there is a seqence $t_n\to+\infty$ such that $\dot c(t_n)\to\dot c(0)$.

In any case, if you take a little (compact) piece of hypersurface $H$ that contains $c(0)$ and is (say) orthogonal to $\dot c(0)$, we see that (by construction of the sequence $t_n$) the curve $c(t)$ will traverse $H$ infinitely often.

Hence, the set $S\subset\Bbb R$ of $t$ such that for some compact hypersurface patch $H$ containing $c(t)$ and transversal to $\dot c(t)$, $c(t)$ is non-isolated in $H\cap c(\Bbb R)$ is non-empty, since it contains $0$.

$S$ is easily seen to be open in $\Bbb R$. This necessitates the hypothesis that $\dot c(t_n)\to\dot c(0)$. But more is true: compactness of $M$ implies that there is a uniform $r>0$ such that

1. $\forall p\in M,\exp_p:B(0,r)\subset T_pM\to M$ is a diffeomorphism,
2. $\forall p\in M$, the pullback metric $\exp_p^*g$ on the $r$-ball centered at $0$ of $T_pM$ deviates less than some small uniform $\delta>0$ from $g_p$.

This will imply that there exists some positive $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $t\in S$, $(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)\subset S$. Since $S$ is non-empty, this implies $S=\Bbb R$

(**EDIT.** This last point is not true as stands: There are problems with points that are visited infinitely many times. This invalidates the proof.)

As a consequence, the intersection we were considering earlier
$$H\cap c(R)$$
is closed and without isolated points (up until now, we only knew $c(0)$ was not isolated, but $S=\Bbb R$ implies that no point in this intersection is isolated). But it is also countable by some transversality argument (which may require one to slightly perturb the piece of hypersurface $H$). Hence it is a countable perfect set, of which there can be none in a manifold.

Comment: I haven't digested all this yet, but certainly—by dimension considerations—$c\times c$ can only be transverse to the diagonal when either (1) $\dim M = 2$ or (2) $c$ never hits the same point twice.

Comment: @tedshifrin I don't need transversality per se, I only want $T_{(t,t')}c\times c(T_{(t,t')}\Bbb R\times\Bbb R)\oplus T\Delta_M$.

Comment: There is a mistake elsewhere I don't know if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true and not even hard to prove, but you need a trick. Let $c: {\mathbb R}\to M$ be a complete geodesic with compact image (you do not even need $M$ to be closed). Let $\pi: UM\to M$ denote the unit tangent bundle. The geodesic $c$, of course, has a canonical lift to a map $\tilde{c}: {\mathbb R}\to UM$. The image of  $\tilde{c}$ is still compact; it is a trajectory of the *geodesic flow* on $UM$, which is a smooth action of the group $G={\mathbb R}$ on $UM$. Now, it is a general fact of topological dynamics, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461446/is-the-space-of-all-linear-complex-structures-of-mathbbr2n-an-embedded-s?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291773/integral-curve-is-periodic-if-and-only-if-it-is-compact?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391315/are-closed-orbits-of-lie-group-action-embedded/2216157#2216157), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433255/does-compact-orbit-imply-periodicity?noredirect=1&lq=1):

Theorem. Let $G$ be a Lie group and $G\times X\to X$ is a  continuous action of $G$ on a manifold (one needs much less). Suppose that $x\in X$ is a point such that the orbit $Gx$ is closed in $X$. Then the orbit map $G\to Gx\subset X, g\mapsto gx$ defines a homeomorphism $G/G_x\to Gx$, where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$.

The proof that I gave in the answer to the 1st linked question uses Baire category theorem and nothing else.

In your case: Unless $c$ (equivalently, $\tilde{c}$) is a periodic geodesic, its stabilizer in $G$ is trivial and, hence, we obtain a homeomorpism ${\mathbb R}\to \tilde{c}({\mathbb R})$, which is absurd since $\tilde{c}({\mathbb R})$ is compact.