# Exact requirements for Stabilizer-Orbit-theorem for Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let's say a Lie group $G$ acts on $M$. Then the orbit is diffeomorphic to the quotient of the group with the stabilizer ${\rm Orb}(x) \cong G/{\rm Stab}(x)$.

What are the exact requirement for the statement. I.e. has the group act freely or transitive...?

Comment: If you assume properness of the action then this theorem holds. Without properness, it (in general) fails.

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way around, i.e. if $M$ is a manifold and everything is smooth?

Comment: Just think about the action of ${\mathbb Z}$ on the circle generated by a rotation of infinite order. Or, if you want an example of a connected Lie group, take an isometric effective action of ${\mathbb R}$ on the torus $T^2$.

Comment: I think the only key requirement is just Orb($x$) is an embedded submanifold of M, and each of the other conditions is just to deduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "golden standard" here. The most common assumptions under which this theorem holds are:

1. The orbit $Gx\subset M$ is open.

or

2. The orbit $Gx\subset M$ is closed.

or

3. The $G$-action $G\times M\to M$ is proper (which implies 2).

See my answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793837/does-a-continuous-group-action-induce-an-open-map/3796815#3796815), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678375/homeomorphism-from-the-coset-space-g-g-x-to-the-orbit-xg?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461446/is-the-space-of-all-linear-complex-structures-of-mathbbr2n-an-embedded-s/3462165#3462165).

Most of the work goes into proving that the natural map $G/G_x\to Gx$ is a homeomorphism. Once this is done, the diffeomorphism  part follows from the Constant Rank Theorem (either the immersion or the submersion case).

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the case of a principal bundle, I know that the orbit is diffeomorphic to the fiber, i.e. the group. But which of these assumptions above holds in that case. I do not assume a proper group action in my definition. But that the base and total space are manifolds and that the group is a Lie group and the action is free and transitive.

Comment: In the case of a principal fiber bundle, the action is proper. Transitive case is covered by the item (1) in my list (and (2), of course).

Comment: But why is it proper. I do not assume it from the beginning. I just assume that $P,M$ is a manifold, $G$ a Lie group and that the action is fiber preserving, free and transitive and that the local trivialization is $G$-equivariant.

Comment: @NicAG It is a nice exercise in understanding the definitions, one can find a detailed proof somewhere at MSE. Try to prove it for one hour, if you can't prove it in one hour, I will add a proof or a link

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/converse-to-quotient-manifold-theorem-exercise-in-lee-smooth-manifolds

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. That is what I was looking for