# Sufficient condition for a discrete homeomorphism group action to be properly discontinous.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, group-actions

First of all, let's agree on a definition. Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\Gamma$ be a topological group.

> A continous group action $\alpha:\Gamma \times X\to X$ is **properly discontinous** iff for every compact $K$ we have $K\cap \gamma K\neq \varnothing$ only for a finite number of $\gamma \in \Gamma$.

Let $X$ be a $T_2$, second countable, locally compact space and let $G$ be a subgroup of the homeomorphism group of $X$ (equipped with the compact-open topology). Let's suppose that $G$ acts on $X$ transitively and with compact stabilizers:
$$\alpha:G\times X\to X.$$
Clearly this induces an action of every subgroup $\Gamma \leq G$ on $X$, simply given by $\alpha|_{\Gamma \times X}$. Now here comes the request of the problem:

> Prove that if $\Gamma \leq G$ is a discrete subgroup of the group of the homeomorphism of $X$, then $\alpha|_{\Gamma \times X}$ is a properly discontinous action.

I really don't know where to start with this problem. I feel just that there is so much going on here. I tried even to treat the case $\Gamma=G$ first to simplify things but I really don't know how to approach this.

Comment: What makes you think that this claim is true?

Comment: The fact that it was in my sheet of exercises... (it's not intended to sound rude, I'm just being honest).

Comment: Note "properly discontinuous" can be defined differently

Comment: What does "compact stabilisers" mean?

Comment: That the stabilizers of the group actions are compact subspaces of $G$

Comment: I thought I removed this comment: It was written when I did not read the question carefully.

Comment: I think a place to start looking is at the fact that $\Gamma$ is discrete under the compact-open topology. I.e., for any compact $K$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\gamma K$ for which $\gamma$ is the only element of $\Gamma$ which carries $K$ into $V$.

Comment: I forgot in the prevous comment that for given $K, V$, $\{\gamma \in \Gamma : \gamma K\subseteq V\}$ is only a sub-basis element of the compact-open topology. So the best you can say for any given $\gamma$ is that there is a finite collection of compact sets $K_i$ and neighborhoods $V_i$ of $\gamma K_i$ for which $\gamma$ is the only element of $\Gamma$ that carries every $K_i$ into $V_i$. Still, I think this is the key to your solution.

Comment: Do you already know that each orbit map induces a homeomorphism $G/G_x\to X$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know that this is a bijection by orbit-stabilizer theorem, but I don't know how to prove that it's an homeomorphism.

Comment: Then take a look at my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461446/is-the-space-of-all-linear-complex-structures-of-mathbbr2n-an-embedded-s/3462165#3462165).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Got it!